# [R| How to group the same value within a column and transpose into the row

Tags: r

Here is my data set:

```
1   066-01127-1602 | is Conditional | 066-01127-1301
2   066-01127-1602 | is Conditional | 066-01127-1101
3   066-01127-1602 | is Conditional | 066-01127-1601
4   066-01127-1602 | is Conditional | 9008000-10000
```

I have no idea how i can transform the data to become in the same row, like this:

```
1   066-01127-1602 | is Conditional | 066-01127-1301 | is Conditional | 066-01127-1101 | is Conditional | 066-01127-1601 | is Conditional |  9008000-10000
```

---

Sorry for my mistake, I should be have no separator and I rewrite the suggested code:

```
list <- by(result[-1],result[1],function(x) do.call(paste,x));paste(names(list),list)
```

Result:

```
Search P/N: 066-01127-1602
[1] "is Conditional 066-01127-1301" "is Conditional 066-01127-1101" "is Conditional 066-01127-1601" "is Conditional 9008000-10000"
```

I can generate the list successfully and now i have to export into .xlsx but this error occurs:

```
> write.xlsx(list, "List.xlsx")

Error in as.data.frame.default(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"by"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: My first query would be, why? Secondly, if you must, search here for "[r] reshape long wide"

Comment: `a <- by(data[-1],data[1],function(x) do.call(paste,c(sep='|',collapse='|',x)));paste(names(a),a,sep='|')`

Comment: Originally I use the existing excel macro to do this, but i take long time and i decide to use R to rewrite it into this fix format

Comment: If I create a new data set and use for-loop and if-then statement, is it ok? if no record, then create a new row. if have record, append the list.

Comment: whenever you are responding to someone ensure you type @TungManLok, eg `@Onyambu` will be addressed to me.

Comment: you can remove `sep` but do not remove `collapse`, you can have it as `collapse = '  '`

Comment: @Onyambu oh i added back the collapse and the error still occurs

Error in as.data.frame.default(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"by"’ to a data.frame

Comment: your aim should not be the `list`, your aim is `h = paste(names(list),list)` `h` is what you want to write. try `cat(h,file='h.txt',sep='\n')`

Comment: i have output the txt file successfully. thanks for your help/